# What's wrong with my logic for friday the thirteenth usaco program? I've tried everything

Tags: java

I don't understand why this code isn't working. I had an array of the number of days in the months and then I for looped it from 1900 to 1900+N+1 to get all the friday the thirteenths of the years. and then I for looped from the months. I figured out that for each of the days whether it is 31 days,28, or 30, the starting day say monday, the next month's starting day would be 3 days after monday. So I did that and I also figured out that each thirteenth days afterwards is just 13%7 -1 days after the starting day so I did that yet my code still doesn't work. The output is always 2,134,536 or some garbage for the values of the array whenever I try to print it. Can someone please help me on my logic on why it's not right?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class friday {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // the input file 
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("friday.txt"));


        // Use StringTokenizer vs. readLine/split -- lots faster
        int N = Integer.parseInt(f.readLine());


        int numdaysinmonth[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

        int currentindexday = 0;

        int numberofThirtday[] = {0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0};

        //for loop from years
        for (int x = 1900; x < x + N; x++) {


             if(x%4 == 0 && x%100 != 0 || x%400==0 ){

             numdaysinmonth[1] = 29;

             }

             else{

             numdaysinmonth[1] = 28;
             }


            //the number of days to add to get from teh first starting day        

            int daystoadd = 0; 


            int startingday = 0;

            for (int y = 0; y < numdaysinmonth.length; y++) {

                if(numdaysinmonth[y] == 31){

                    daystoadd = 3;

                }

                else if(numdaysinmonth[y] == 30){
                    daystoadd = 2;
                }

                else if(numdaysinmonth[y] == 29){
                    daystoadd = 1;
                }

                else if(numdaysinmonth[y] == 28){
                    daystoadd = 0;
                }
    //each thirteenth day is the first day adding 5 to get the day 13%7 -1 
                currentindexday = startingday + 5;

                if(currentindexday>6){
                    currentindexday = currentindexday%7;
                }

                numberofThirtday[currentindexday]++;
                startingday  += daystoadd;
            }
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < numberofThirtday.length; n++) {
            System.out.println(numberofThirtday[n]);
        }
        out.close();                                   
        System.exit(0);                               
    }

}
```

Comment: Quick word of advice: Never state, `"I tried everything"` because it's always not true since we and you know that you haven't tried the correct approach.

Comment: no i also tried debugging and it didn't help at all. I just get garbage and I printed out the values and i still get garbage.

Comment: [Several similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+friday+the+thirteenth+program+usaco+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)